# Storing a 2D map in a SQL database with an efficient primary key schema

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a small game in javascript which relies on a map rendered from a collection of coordinates (held in a database). I am at the point of designing the database and wanted to know which of two methods was considerable preferable.

The world is mapped to 1000x1000 tiles and each coordinate pair (x,y) represents a unique tile with its own properties.

I've never constructed an object/database like this before, so my instinct was to use the unique coordinate pair as the primary key which would ensure no collision as well as give me an obvious way of allocating the primary keys. Thus tile x: 844, y:444 would be represented with the ID of 08440444. Would this make it more computationally difficult to grab an X coordinate from a given ID than the second option? Is there a better way of constructing an ID out of an [x,y] pair?

```
                                       ┌──────────────────┐                                    
                                       │   table: tiles   │                                    
                    ┌──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┐                  
                    │      coord       │    treasures     │      people      │                  
                    │                  │                  │                  │                  
                    ├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┤                  
                    │     integer      │                  │                  │                  
                    │   primary key    │     hasMany      │     hasMany      │                  
                    │ unique x,y coord │   relationship   │   relationship   │                  
                    │                  │                  │                  │                  
                    └──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

or

```
                                      ┌──────────────────┐                                     
                                      │   table: tiles   │                                     
┌──────────────────┬──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│        id        │        x         │        y         │    treasures     │      people      │
│                  │                  │                  │                  │                  │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│     integer      │     integer      │     integer      │                  │                  │
│   primary key    │   represents x   │   represents y   │     hasMany      │     hasMany      │
│ autoincrementing │    coordinate    │    coordinate    │   relationship   │   relationship   │
│                  │                  │                  │                  │                  │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: you may want the concat'd version to use as a key, but having the coords as separate columns can be handy for searching later, like grabbing a range, line, or rectangle of tiles...

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the advice -- would that be cheaper computationally than implementing the separate columns as computed properties that derive the coordinate from the id? or is the tradeoff requiring more storage space for the extra columns vs more computation for the derived properties?

Comment: yes, the less work thats need to do the query, the faster the query will perform. if you need to unpack a coord datum for every logical comparison, that's more work than comparing a ready-to-go value. think about grabbing col>10 AND col<20 without distinct col values. yes, you can do string operations to make the compares, but doing no operations is better.

Comment: Soon as the words postgresql and coordinates are used together it's time to start looking at postgis.

Answer (score 0):

The key to making your game engine perform is to keep your database as compact as possible. Your tile "environment" is well-defined, so make a data structure that matches your design:

- Tile IDs use the `smallint` data type, saves you 50% in storage and network traffic compared to regular `integer`s.
- If you really need a PK, create it from the tile IDs, do not use a `serial` data type or a separate column unless your data model is certain to benefit from it. You may get by just fine without a PK and use a non-unique index on the tile IDs instead.

In fact, you do not even need a "tiles" table with the information provided above. You can get by with a "treasures" and a "people" table that both have 'x' and 'y' columns. Only when you have specific tile properties through a "has-a" or "is-a" (1-1) relationship would you benefit from a "tiles" table. Also, do not define referential relationships between the tables unless you really need them, they incur a lot of overhead to be maintained.

In short, this may be all you need:

```
CREATE TABLE tileproperties (
  x      smallint,
  y      smallint,
  prop1  integer,
  prop2  varchar,
  ...
);
CREATE INDEX idx_tileproperties ON tileproperties(x, y);

CREATE TABLE treasures (
  x      smallint,
  y      smallint,
  id     smallint, 
  t_type integer,  -- this may be a FK to a table defining a type of treasure
  prop1  integer,
  prop2  varchar,
  ...
);
CREATE INDEX idx_treasures ON treasures(x, y, id); -- may also be UNIQUE or PK

CREATE TABLE people(
  x      smallint,
  y      smallint,
  id     smallint, 
  p_type integer,  -- this may be a FK to a table defining a type of people
  prop1  integer,
  prop2  varchar,
  ...
);
CREATE INDEX idx_people ON people(x, y, id); -- may also be UNIQUE or PK
```

Comment: thanks for the response! by non-unique index of the tile ID's do you mean if i was combining an index for 11,1 [x,y] i would be given an id of 111 whereas if i was combining 1,11 [x,y] i would be allocated the same id?

in my javascript i rely heavily on the relationships to provide easy access to associated properties, for instance I can quickly look up (quick syntax, if not computation) tile.interactions to look at all of the interactions allowed by that tile. is it correct that in this model i would instead look at the interactions table and search the x,y columns? thanks again!